# JAVA: Identify a prime number

Tags: java

I wrote a code to identify a prime number. There's no syntax error, but when it's not a prime number it loops again to enter a positive integer. It's supposed to be "To try again press 1 and to exit press 2".

Here's my code below:

```
import java.util.*;
public class TRY
{
 static Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 public static void main (String[] arg)
{

   int n;

   System.out.println("Identify the if it's a prime number");

   while (true){

           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("Enter a positive integer:  ");
           n = Scan.nextInt();

        if (n>0)
           {
                   boolean isPrime = true;
                   for (int i = 2; i <= n/2;i++)
                   {
                    if (n % i == 0 ){
                                   isPrime = false;
                           }  
                   }
                   if (isPrime){
                           System.out.println("The integer you entered " + n + " is a PRIME NUMBER!");
                   }
                   else
                   {
                           System.out.println("The integer you entered " + n + " is not a PRIME NUMBER!");
                           continue;
                   }
                   System.out.println();
                   System.out.println("To try again press 1 and to exit press 2");

                   if (Scan.nextInt() == 1)
                   {
                           continue;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                           System.out.println("Thank you!");
                           break;
                   }


     }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may wonder why someone downvoted your question ... please have a look here : [ask]

Comment: put an appropriate title. No one will google _"Guys I need a little help please"_

Comment: I'm sorry, I won't do that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the 
`continue;` 
after line 
`System.out.println("The integer you entered " + n + " is not a PRIME NUMBER!");`.

What `continue;` does is that it skips all the section of the loop that comes after it and performs the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks bro! I already figured it out! :)